# MySQL Database not starting - ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file - XAMPP OS X

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, xampp

I'm using XAMPP on OS X Maveriks and I'm running XAMPP to have MySQL and Apache.

It was running great and no problem but today when I tried to run MySQL from os-x-manager, it says Starting then Stopped.

I searched and used this command in terminal :

> sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

it gives the following error:

> Starting MySQL
>   . ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Boshras-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).

I searched for the PID file, it wasn't found, i created it using and rm *.local.err before it

> touch Boshras-MacBook-Pro.local.pid

but the pid file disappears every time i try to start MySQL. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use **SUDO**

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mysql does not have permission to the folder where the pid file is located in.

Solution working for my case:

1. Check your error log at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Boshras-MacBook-Pro.local.err
2. If there is something like this in the log: ...[Note] Unable to delete pid file: Permission denied..., which means mysql does not have the permission to 
   your mysql folder
3. Use the following command in terminal to grant the permission: sudo chown -R mysql /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql